# pymongo json returns bson string

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Pymongo db im just not sure how to get it to only return the value. I can't really think of away other than parsing the string it returns to get the value only.

```
for col_name in col_list:
    col = db[col_name]
    for x in col.find( {}, {'name.details.stuff': 1, '_id': 0} ):
        for key, value in x.items():
            story = "the cat went after those %s/"%value
            print(story )
```

output:

```
the cat went after those {'name': {'details': 'things'}}.
```

i would like for the script to only return things not the json/bson stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` returns an iterable cursor of `dict`s, so you can get the individual value using normal dictionary operations; e.g.

```
for x in col.find( {}, {'name.details': 1, '_id': 0} ):
    story = f"the cat went after those {x.get('name').get('details')}/"
    print(story)
```

or

```
for x in col.find( {}, {'name.details': 1, '_id': 0} ):
    story = f"the cat went after those {x['name']['details']}/"
    print(story)
```